# planes3d expands and draws the area based on the sphere's radius

Tags: r, rgl

The planes3d expands and draws the area based on the sphere's radius.  Is there a way to suppress this?  More desirable for me would be to clip the drawing area, though.

```
library(rgl)
z <- c(0,0,1)
y <- c(0,1,0)
x <- c(1,0,0)
bg3d(color = "white")
rgl.spheres(x, y, z, r = 0.02, color = "grey") 
planes3d(1, 0, 0, 0, col = 'blue', alpha = 0.6, size = 0)
planes3d(0, 1, 0, 0, col = 'red', alpha = 0.6, size = 0)
planes3d(0, 0, 1, 0, col = 'green', alpha = 0.6, size = 0)
view3d(theta=230, phi=-30, zoom=1, fov=0)
snapshot3d("r0_02.png", fmt="png", width=640, height=480, webshot=F)

clear3d()
rgl.spheres(x, y, z, r = 0.2, color = "grey") 
planes3d(1, 0, 0, 0, col = 'blue', alpha = 0.6, size = 0)
planes3d(0, 1, 0, 0, col = 'red', alpha = 0.6, size = 0)
planes3d(0, 0, 1, 0, col = 'green', alpha = 0.6, size = 0)
view3d(theta=230, phi=-30, zoom=1, fov=0)
snapshot3d("r0_2.png", fmt="png", width=640, height=480, webshot=F)
```

I'm expecting a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `planes3d()`, which draws infinite planes, clipped to the bounding box.

There might be a workaround where you put the planes in one subscene and apply clipping there, and put the spheres in a different subscene with no clipping, but that would be tricky to implement.

A better approach is to use `quads3d()` instead of `planes3d()`.  With your example, this would be

```r
library(rgl)
z <- c(0,0,1)
y <- c(0,1,0)
x <- c(1,0,0)
corner1 <- c(1,1,2,2) # vector entry with corner of square
corner2 <- c(2,3,3,2) # other corner
bg3d(color = "white")
rgl.spheres(x, y, z, r = 0.2, color = "grey") 
# planes3d(1, 0, 0, 0, col = 'blue', alpha = 0.6, size = 0)
quads3d(cbind(0, y[corner1], z[corner2]),
        col = "blue", alpha = 0.6)
#planes3d(0, 1, 0, 0, col = 'red', alpha = 0.6, size = 0)
quads3d(cbind(x[corner1], 0, z[corner2]), 
        col = 'red', alpha = 0.6)
#planes3d(0, 0, 1, 0, col = 'green', alpha = 0.6, size = 0)
quads3d(cbind(x[corner1], y[corner2], 0), 
        col = 'green', alpha = 0.6)
view3d(theta=230, phi=-30, zoom=1, fov=0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In an earlier version of this answer, the spheres showed weird black blobs on the edges.  That was due to a bug in `rgl` that has been fixed.  This image was drawn with the development version 1.2.10.

Comment: Sure, the display quality of spheres generated by rglwidget is poor.  Increasing the value of this.initSphere(16, 16) in the init.src.js mitigates this issue, but it cannot be controlled from rglwidget options.
Sorry for going off topic from the original question.

Comment: @大根おろし:  The bug that was causing the bad display has been fixed in the devel version.